# Vaadin focus Grid inside Panel

Tags: focus, vaadin

I have two Grids (both in its own panel), and want to navigate between them using the Tab Key.

To do that I'm trying to focus the Grid inside a Panel (If Tab is pressed, the Grid should gain focus, so I can use the up/Down key to select Items).

Vaadin doesn't provide a `.focus()` method for Grid. Is there any solution so I can focus the Grid anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Here is small example which shows working scenario with

1. `Tab` key pressed
2. Arrows down/up should points to a row (exactly in `Valo` this is presented as contour around one cell)
3. Space makes row selected (if `Grid` has enabled selection!) - row should be highlighted.

**Code example:**

```
@Theme ( ValoTheme.THEME_NAME )
public class MyUI extends UI {
    public class A {
        String a;
        String b;
        A(String a, String b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
        // getters & setters
    }

    @Override
    protected void init ( VaadinRequest vaadinRequest )
    {
        Grid g = new Grid();
        List<A> list = Arrays.asList(new A("a", "b"), new A("aa", "bb"), 
                                     new A("aaa", "bbb"));
        BeanItemContainer<A> items = new BeanItemContainer<>(A.class, list);
        g.setContainerDataSource(items);

        Panel p = new Panel(g);
        setContent(p);
    }
}
```

*Tested: Vaadin 7.5, Java 8, Tomcat 8.*

You could try to use:

```
setFocusedComponent(p);
```

after `setContent(p)`. This should exactly tells Vaadin to make panel focused. But you still must press `tab` - once or more (depending on rest of components, which you placed on screen).

But make sure:

1. Grid is selectable.
2. Maybe you should press `Tab` more than once.
3. Depending on `Theme` there could be different effects of getting focus (or even select state). It is also possible that you use some predefined project which has blocked `grid` css to make it lighter. So check if you can highlight one row by click on it.

Without more information I can't help more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Sadly, setFocusedComponents focuses just the panel itself and not the Grid inside it. (Means after focusing the Panel i can still not navigate trough the grid because the Panel gets the key events). Did it work in your application?

Comment: In sample above, yes - the panel gets focus, so you need press `tab` and then you can see that first row of grid gets focus, and you could use Up/Down keys to move. But in `Valo` that focus in grid means that you see contour around one grid cell. To select all row you need to press `space` button.

Answer (score 1):

The OP write in an edit:

> **Solved the problem using Javascript/Jquery. Added this to my Panel that contains the Grid:**
>
> ```
> public class FileTable extends Panel
>    {
>
>    String id;
>    public FileTable(String id)
>    {
>     this.id=id;
>     Grid table = new Grid();
>     initGrid();
>     fileTable.setId(id);
>    }
>
>    public void focus()
>    {
>      JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("$(\"#"+id+" table:first td:first\").click();");
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: ([Converted an answer in an edit to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))